# error code 0xc0000225 after installing dual boot linux

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, data-recovery

When I try to boot to Windows 8 I get error code 0xc0000225 ever since I installed ubuntu. I was using windows 8 developer preview so I don't have an installation disk disk to do a recovery.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6579500/

any help appreciated, I have some important files in windows that I didn't back up.

Comment: did you installed ubuntu through wubi?

Comment: no, I installed from a USB, I may have formatted the partitions incorrectly

Comment: plz upload gparted screenshot.